# How to send e-mail from form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

I am new in programing and WordPress. I want to send a e-mail from my form with a message, phone, ect. Can anyone tell me how can i do that?
Here is my code so far...

```
 <div id="form">


 <?php 
          add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_content_type');
          function set_content_type($content_type){
          return 'text/html';
          }    

    ?>
         <div id="name">
         <p id="username"> Name:&nbsp; </p>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
         </div>
         <div id="name">
         <p id="username"> Email: &nbsp; </p>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
         </div>
         <div id="name">
         <p id="username"> Phone:&nbsp;  </p>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
         </div>
         <div id="name">
         <p id="username"> Message: </p>
         <input type="text" name="message" class="textarea">
     </div>
    <input type="button" value="SEND" id="btn"> 
  </div>
```

Comment: i use this function for sending mail but not working <?php add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_content_type'); function set_content_type($content_type){ return 'text/html'; }

Comment: have you tried `wp_email` ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Answer (score 6):

To send mail from a form with following fields, open a new file and copy these lines and save (e.g. mail.php):

```
<?php
 //sending mail
 if(isset($_POST['sub']))
 {
   $uname=$_POST['uname']; 
   $mailid=$_POST['mailid'];
   $phone=$_POST['phone'];
   $message=$_POST['message'];
   if(mail($uname,$mailid,$phone,$message))
   {
     echo "mail sent";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "mail failed";
   }
 }
?>
<form name="frm" method="post" action="#">
 <label for="uname">Name:</label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="uname" id="uname"><br/>
 <label for="mailid">Email:</label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="mailid" id="mailid"><br/>
 <label for="mobile">Phone:</label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone"><br/>
 <label for="message">Message:</label>                                   
 <input type="text" value="" name="message" id="message"><br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" id="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: how can I make this a function ?, like so I can call it from jQuery, it sends an email, then return a message with success/fail. ?

Comment: can I send emails from my local computer ?

Comment: Isn't the mail function wrongly called twice on the code above?

Answer (score 3):

It will have to be *much more* complicated than what you have at the moment.

My **first recommendation** would be to use some, *rather top-heavy*, form plugins, But you will save yourself a lot of time and trouble like that.

http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7

My **2nd recommendation** would be to follow a popular tutorial for a full custom form to email script.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-built-in-contact-form-for-your-wordpress-theme

**Note:** Beware of spam bots and various other possible dangers of just putting a public form up on the web. If's very possible that you will have a hole in your custom code and a *could* cause some damage if exploited by the right person.

Comment: can I send emails from my local computer ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Yes you can, but you need to setup Postfix if you are on MAMP. http://foxinni.com/screens/Postfix-20140512-093049.png See: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html