# How to get my form to send submissions to an email?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I apologize in advance if this question has already been beaten to death but I'm having a hard time figuring how to get my form to send submissions to my email address. I've tried looking all over online and everything I see is about formatting the form with html and css but nothing that explains the scripts involved or how it needs to be set up to actually send to an email address.

```
  <style>

  input[type=text], input[type=number], select[name=province]{ font-family: arial; width:100%;  
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5; padding: 10px 20px;}
input[name=ffirstname] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=lastname] {width:49%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=address] {width:65.6667%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=unit] {width:32.3337%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=city] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
select[name=province] {width:24%; margin-left:1%;}
input[name=postal] {width:24%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=email] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=phone] {width:49%; margin-left:1%;}

input[class=submit] {

  background-color: #f05a28;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none; !important;
  outline: none; !important ;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none; !important;
 }
 </style>

 <form action method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmhot" verified="0" id="huge_it_contact_form_3" class="hugeit_form">

  <br><input type="text" name="ffirstname" placeholder="First Name"/><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
  <br><br><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/><input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="Unit"/></br>
  <br><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"/><select name="province" form="form1">
<option value="ab">AB</option>
  <option value="BC">BC</option>
  <option value="BC">MB</option>
  <option value="NB">NB</option>
<option value="NL">NL</option>
<option value="NS">NS</option>
<option value="ON">ON</option>
<option value="PE">PE</option>
<option value="QC">QC</option>
<option value="SK">SK</option>
</select><input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="Postal Code"/></br>
<br><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country"/></br>
<Br><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone#"/></br>
<br> <br><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Next" id="hugeit_preview_button__submit_21"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send e-mail from form in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927682/how-to-send-e-mail-from-form-in-wordpress)

Comment: html doesn't do emailing, you have to script (php, perl, whatever... ) the form to either submit to itself, or to another page, then have that process the post request, get the values, and, important, VALIDATE to avoid any nasty use of the form, then have it email. PHP for example has mail() which accepts the subject, body, to, from, etc, parameters. Your form css etc are irrelevant to this process, that's just styling and layout, unrelated to emailing by scripting.

Comment: where can i find out to make such a script, or is there i can copy

Comment: google it, it's a standard thing, most of them really suck though, radically bad and insecure, just determine the language you'll use, then search: [language] form emailer script . I like this one: https://github.com/smxi/php-html-mime-mail but it's probably way too complicated for your needs. Most of the scripts out there are terrible, all you actually need is a small block of code, and make the page submit to itself, and put that block in the top of the page. I won't post a truncated version of what I use because it depends on security and cleanup libraries, but the basic idea is simple.

Answer (score 0):

```html
//using a sample html form as this below, i created a php script //that will perform this task`
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thank you</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="form-to-email.php">
    <p>
        <label>Enter name : </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email address : </label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Message: </label><br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="10" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
    </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>

// then below is the php script called form-to-email.php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>form-to-email.php</title>
  </head>
 <body>
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "steloffs2006@gmail.com"; // your email address
$subject = "My contact form";   // the subject you want to see
$body = " You have received a new message from the user $name \n" ." Email address: $email \n" . " Here is the message: $message";
mail($to,$sub`enter code here`ject,$body);
echo "<h1>Thank you for your time </h1>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble, since I'm using wordress i've discovered that i have to use a workaround for using php, so i'm using the plugin "php code snipets" and it allows me to insert a shortcode of php ive written an call it within a widget on my page. The name of the file is "formsend.php" and i put this into the "action" field of the form, but it doesnt look the email is sending still   `<form action="formsend.php" method="post">`

Comment: `$name = $_POST['ffirstname'];
$email = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['address'];

$to = "arshigtx@hotmail.com"; 
$subject = "My contact form";   
$body = " You have received a new message from the user $name Here is the message: $message";"
mail($to,$subject,$body);`